# How to see detailed cost breakdown for Azure subscription

Tags: azure

I can't understand how to see the detailed breakdown of costs behind my Azure charges.

I tried the cost management and billing options within the Azure portal, but just got lots of graphs with no clear idea whether I am looking at totals or how to drill into.

I expected to be able to download detail, but can only see confusing graphs

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found you need to follow this exact process to download the actual transactional data from the portal:

1. Azure portal -> Cost analysis
2. Select relevant dates from the menu at the top
3. Granularity -> daily
4. Group by -> Meter
5. Change the small graph symbol in the top right to be a table

Now can chose Export and you will be able to download all detail to excel / csv to analyse yourself without having to use the Azure pre-canned 'helpful' graphs.

As far as I can tell if any of the above steps are not followed, the download doesn't give you the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To see usage details for an Azure subscription:

- Go to *Cost Management + Billing*
- Select your subscription
- On the *Overview* blade, click the *Manage* button which takes you to the [Billing Overview](https://account.azure.com/Subscriptions?appId=Ibiza_BillingOverviewCommandBar)
- Select the subscription to see details for
- The sidebar on the right has actions you can do. One is *Download usage details*